# Re-run script after localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a script to show/hide some content when a checkbox is checked. Since my content is divided in multiple pages I need the checkbox to stay checked when you change pages. I've read about `localStorage`, tried that and it works nice.

The proble however is that my script isn't firing when you change page. So the checkbox keeps checked but the content which shouldn't be visible is still visible.

So what I have (don't mind the Twig tags, the script itself works!!)

```js
$(function() {
  var test = localStorage.input === 'true' ? true : false;
  $('#stock').prop('checked', test || false);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('{{ product.url | url }}?format=json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.product.variants, function(index, variant) {
      if (variant.stock.on_stock) {
        $('.item-image-container.{{ product.id }}')
          .find('figure')
          .after('<div class="label_ship {{ product.id }}"></div>');
        $('.label_ship.{{ product.id }}').addClass('active');
      }
    });
  });

  $('#stock').change(function() {
    localStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
    if (this.checked && !$('.label_ship.{{ product.id }}')
        .hasClass('active')) {
      $('.stock-check-{{ product.id }}').fadeOut('fast');
    } else {
      $('.stock-check-{{ product.id }}').fadeIn('fast');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stock-box">
  <input type="checkbox" value="" id="stock">
  <label for="stock">show only on stock</label>
</div>
```

Can anybody help with that? Is it perhaps better to wrap everything in a functioin and then re-run that function when page changes??

Comment: `$(function(){ //code })` is the same as `$(document).ready(function(){ //code })`

Comment: Off-topic remark: `localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false` is exactly the same as `localStorage.input === 'true'` and `test || false` is exactly the same as just `test`.

Comment: Also, why can't you just do `if( test ) { /* show content */ } else { /* hide content */ }`?

Comment: Ok thx I did a copy/paste from an other topic since I never heard of localStorage... I'll try to clean up the code

Answer (score 0):

The function you're running to fade in/out the content is bound to `change` events on `#stock`. However, you only bind it *after* you change its value in the first `$(function(){})` block. I'm suspecting the problem would be solved by moving the value-change code to after the binding code.

Also, do take a look at the comments to your question, as there are some good suggestions there :)